# Passing in a PHP variable into a Twitter Callback URL

Tags: php, callback, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want twitter to send a user back to

```
site.com/person.php?person=$curr_person
```

where `$curr_person` is a session variable stored in `$_SESSION['person']` and obtained from `$_GET['person']`

Problem is when Twitter redirects back to my site `$curr_person` is not evaluated and is taken literally. I assume the redirect doesn't hit my server...how can I get the call back `URL` to be evaluated properly?

Thanks

Comment: What does the code look like where you generate the redirection url?

Comment: twitter handles the redirect...I just set the URL and it's the same as what I have on the second line... site.com/person.php?person=$curr_person

Comment: Yeah, this string on the second line, where does it show up in your code? Is it inside double or single quotes? Single quotes won't parse PHP Variables inline etc. etc., without code we can't say very much

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is not evaluated is probably because you entered it as a part of the string like that:

```
$twitter->call('site.com/person.php?person=$curr_person');
```

But there are two solutions:

1. **Concatenate**:

   ```
   $twitter->call('site.com/person.php?person=' . $curr_person);
   ```
2. Use **double quotes**:

   ```
   $twitter->call("site.com/person.php?person=$curr_person");
   ```

Hope this helps.

Ps. Of course I am assuming you are passing this URL to some method (like `$twitter->call()`), so do not just copy the code - just get familiar with the way both solutions differ from the code at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: It's *strongly* recommended to `urlencode()` a dynamic added url query value.

Comment: Thanks Tadeck!..but I am not passing into anything on my end...i simply entered it into a field here:https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new  @unset can you give me more info on urlencode?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: If you create URL queries with dynamic data, you should encode them with urlencode. Please check the manual for usage. It's pretty simple: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @algorithmicCoder If you entered it on Twitter settings page, then it will definitely not work and you can not solve it by doing something like that. If you are storing this variable within session, just leave it there and do not pass it in URL - it will be preserved between initial call to Twitter and the callback from Twitter. I believe there is also another option, but it would require giving custom (acceptable to Twitter - this is another subject) URL as a callback whenever you redirect user to Twitter.

Comment: @unset Correct, `urlencode()` would be great (especially because it was passed in GET parameters), except not in this case - OP supplies the value somewhere else, as you probably know.

Comment: but i need the variable to get the user back to the right page

Comment: @algorithmicCoder I just said you can store it in the session variables :) That means you will be able to read the value stored in session and then direct user to the appropriate page. Or alternatively you can just give callback URL to Twitter at the time you are making request to it - see OAuth documentation.